# Extract value from json and filter it using python

Tags: python, json

I'm very new to python.I'm learning it.

I have json file which contains the following json data.

```
{
"document_tone": {
"tone_categories": [
  {
    "category_id": "emotion_tone", 
    "tones": [
      {
        "tone_name": "Anger", 
        "score": 0.041202, 
        "tone_id": "anger"
      }, 
      {
        "tone_name": "Disgust", 
        "score": 0.054272, 
        "tone_id": "disgust"
      }, 
      {
        "tone_name": "Fear", 
        "score": 0.080706, 
        "tone_id": "fear"
      }, 
      {
        "tone_name": "Joy", 
        "score": 0.813125, 
        "tone_id": "joy"
      }, 
      {
        "tone_name": "Sadness", 
        "score": 0.155878, 
        "tone_id": "sadness"
      }
    ], 
    "category_name": "Emotion Tone"
  }, 
  {
    "category_id": "writing_tone", 
    "tones": [
      {
        "tone_name": "Analytical", 
        "score": 0.0, 
        "tone_id": "analytical"
      }, 
      {
        "tone_name": "Confident", 
        "score": 0.0, 
        "tone_id": "confident"
      }, 
      {
        "tone_name": "Tentative", 
        "score": 0.0, 
        "tone_id": "tentative"
      }
    ], 
    "category_name": "Writing Tone"
  }, 
  {
    "category_id": "social_tone", 
    "tones": [
      {
        "tone_name": "Openness", 
        "score": 0.028, 
        "tone_id": "openness_big5"
      }, 
      {
        "tone_name": "Conscientiousness", 
        "score": 0.314, 
        "tone_id": "conscientiousness_big5"
      }, 
      {
        "tone_name": "Extraversion", 
        "score": 0.944, 
        "tone_id": "extraversion_big5"
      }, 
      {
        "tone_name": "Agreeableness", 
        "score": 0.982, 
        "tone_id": "agreeableness_big5"
      }, 
      {
        "tone_name": "Emotional Range", 
        "score": 0.865, 
        "tone_id": "neuroticism_big5"
      }
    ], 
    "category_name": "Social Tone"
  }
]
}
}
```

First I want to extract following fields and after extracting the fields I need "tone_name" with highest score.

```
 "tones": [
      {
        "tone_name": "Anger", 
        "score": 0.041202, 
        "tone_id": "anger"
      }, 
      {
        "tone_name": "Disgust", 
        "score": 0.054272, 
        "tone_id": "disgust"
      }, 
      {
        "tone_name": "Fear", 
        "score": 0.080706, 
        "tone_id": "fear"
      }, 
      {
        "tone_name": "Joy", 
        "score": 0.813125, 
        "tone_id": "joy"
      }, 
      {
        "tone_name": "Sadness", 
        "score": 0.155878, 
        "tone_id": "sadness"
      }
    ]
```

My Output should be like : joy

My Code is

```
import json
with open('data.json','r') as f:
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    print line
    parsedJson = json.loads(line)
    print parsedJson
    for tone in parsedJson['document_tone']['tone_categories'][0]['tones']:
        print(tone['tone_name'])
```

My data.json file contains

```
"{\n  \"document_tone\": {\n    \"tone_categories\": [\n      {\n            
 \"category_id\": \"emotion_tone\", \n        \"tones\": [\n                        
 {\n            \"tone_name\": \"Anger\", \n            \"score\": 
 0.372974, \n            \"tone_id\": \"anger\"\n          }, \n          
 {\n            \"tone_name\": \"Disgust\", \n            \"score\": 
 0.114389, \n            \"tone_id\": \"disgust\"\n          }, \n          
 {\n            \"tone_name\": \"Fear\", \n            \"score\": 
 0.083108, \n            \"tone_id\": \"fear\"\n          }, \n          
 {\n            \"tone_name\": \"Joy\", \n            \"score\": 
 0.028716, \n            \"tone_id\": \"joy\"\n          }, \n          
 {\n            \"tone_name\": \"Sadness\", \n            \"score\": 
 0.461562, \n            \"tone_id\": \"sadness\"\n          }\n        
 ], \n        \"category_name\": \"Emotion Tone\"\n      }, \n      
 {\n        \"category_id\": \"writing_tone\", \n        \"tones\": 
 [\n          {\n            \"tone_name\": \"Analytical\", \n            
 \"score\": 0.722, \n            \"tone_id\": \"analytical\"\n          
 }, \n          {\n            \"tone_name\": \"Confident\", \n            
 \"score\": 0.0, \n            \"tone_id\": \"confident\"\n          
 }, \n          {\n            \"tone_name\": \"Tentative\", \n              
 \"score\": 0.0, \n            \"tone_id\": \"tentative\"\n          
 }\n        ], \n        \"category_name\": \"Writing Tone\"\n      }, 
 \n      {\n        \"category_id\": \"social_tone\", \n        
 \"tones\": [\n          {\n            \"tone_name\": \"Openness\", 
 \n            \"score\": 0.015, \n            \"tone_id\": 
 \"openness_big5\"\n          }, \n          {\n            
 \"tone_name\": \"Conscientiousness\", \n            \"score\": 0.045, 
 \n            \"tone_id\": \"conscientiousness_big5\"\n          }, 
 \n          {\n            \"tone_name\": \"Extraversion\", \n            
 \"score\": 0.722, \n            \"tone_id\": \"extraversion_big5\"\n          
 }, \n          {\n            \"tone_name\": \"Agreeableness\", \n            
 \"score\": 0.706, \n            \"tone_id\": \"agreeableness_big5\"\n          
 }, \n          {\n            \"tone_name\": \"Emotional Range\", \n               
 \"score\": 0.974, \n            \"tone_id\": \"neuroticism_big5\"\n          
 }\n        ], \n        \"category_name\": \"Social Tone\"\n      }\n    
 ]\n  }\n}"
```

Comment: import json
json_data=open('data.json')
data=json.load(json_data)
#print (data)
a = data["tone_categories"][0]["tones"]
print a

Answer (score 1):

Basically to do what you want here you just have to navigate your way through the dict till you get your list of tones, then loop through each tone, and for that tone print out its `tone_name`

```
parsedJson = json.loads(jsonFile)
for tone in parsedJson['document_tone']['tone_categories'][0]['tones']:
    print(tone['tone_name'])
# Anger
# Disgust
# Fear
# Joy
# Sadness
```

Here's your fixed code

```
import json

jsonText = None
with open('data.json','r') as f:
    jsonText = f.read()

parsedJson = json.loads(jsonText)

for tone in parsedJson['document_tone']['tone_categories'][0]['tones']:
    print(tone['tone_name'])
```

Comment: import json
json_data=open('data.json')    
data=json.load(json_data)
#print (data)
a = data["tone_categories"][0]["tones"]
print a

Comment: Thanks Racialz.                                                                                               for the code but It is throwing an exception ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: in my example jsonFile is a string containing all the json data, read the file into a string then run it through what i posted

Comment: Racialz, I have coded as you said but still the exception is coming.                       TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: This is my code which is now part of the question it self...Thanks for help

Comment: look at my answer now

Comment: Racialz sorry to ask you again but I'm very new to python so can you please let me know the error that I have made

Comment: Racialz Thanks for the quick response and help...At my end I got same error don't know what is the issue.I can share snapshot

Comment: the code works on the json you posted man, I can't really help you anymore

Comment: Ok Fine...! Thanks for you help I really appreciate